# Lightbox popup won't popup at page load

Tags: jquery, popup, load

Hi I'm trying to make an image to popup at page load but I can't get it to work. I have been following the instructions from this tutorial: http://postyourtutorial.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-lightbox-gallery-on-pageload.aspx

I can get the image to popup in the normal lightbox window when clicking the image link, but it won't popup on page load, what am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('#popup').trigger('click');
});
</script>

<a rel="lightbox" href="img/autolightbox.png" id="popup">Test</a>
```

Comment: include necessary css , image files

Answer (score 1):

You need to init your lightbox plugin within `$(document).ready()`.

Read [this simple guide](http://www.justinbarkhuff.com/lab/lightbox_slideshow/) and everything will be fine :)